# Magento 2 : Missing field "image" in google search console

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

After successful crawled, am seeing Missing field "Image" issue for all PDP pages in the Google search console. I do have all images for Products in my site.

How can i fix this issue. do we have any configuration for this in Magento 2 admin?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get this issue sorted? I've the exact same issue with my Magento 2.4.5 site

Comment: you can add this attribute in the image tag - itemprop="image"

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that each product page contains proper schema markup, specifically the **itemprop="image"** attribute. This attribute should be applied to the main product image on the page. Review your product detail page template to make sure this attribute is correctly applied to the image tag.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
 <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration>
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="meta_type_name" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_meta_tags.phtml" />
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom_meta_tags.phtml

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($product, 'product_base_image')->getUrl();
?>
<meta itemprop="image" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $imageUrl; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering a "Missing field 'image'" issue in Google Search Console for your Magento 2 website, it means that Google is having trouble finding and indexing images on your website. Here are some steps you can take to resolve this issue:

1. Check Your Robots.txt File
2. Image Sitemaps
3. Structured Data Markup
4. Image Alt Tags
5. Image File Names
6. Image URLs
7. Responsive Design
8. Page Load Speed
9. HTTP vs. HTTPS
10. Google's Image Guidelines
11. Fetch as Google
12. Monitor Google Search Console